# Image not getting display in Custom Email Template

Tags: email, email-template, template

I have created a custom email template and added image into the html version

```
<img src="https://c.ap2.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01528000001HUDq" alt="Company Logo" height="64" width="750"/>
```

i can see image in preview but after sending an email ,image is not  getting display in mailbox/outlook.
Please suggest

Comment: you need to add org id in image url

Comment: check this post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4641/18731